# Youtube inside PhoneGap application

Tags: iphone, hyperlink, cordova, youtube, embed

i have an application written in Javascript+CSS that i made native with phonegap!
So my application is a webview that loads an html with phonegap.

Inside my application i need to open a youtube video, now if i load the youtube url, my app calls the browser to see the video, it works but user have to switch manually to come back to my application.

My goal is to call the youtube native application and when user close the view of youtube, comes back without any further action!

I write a simple plugin of phonegap, that intercepts the call to youtube and passes to an objective C class the video id...now, how can i call the youtube app?

The behaviour that i want is similar of when user click on an email, where mail application it opens and when user have finished to using, application come back automatically.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the childbrowser plugin to open the youtube page in.

This way you can control when to open and to close the second window.

Take a look here: https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser

Comment: How do you make the ChildBrowser go to lanscape mode?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at Sencha Touch. It's a javascript / css framework that you can include in your UIWebview webapp. If you use this framework, you can watch videos right inside your app.

[Here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.Video) is the documentation for doing so. (although you will still need to configure sencha touch, here is the [getting started guide](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/getting-started.html)). Good luck.